# Django decimal InvalidOperation error when beginning

Tags: django, mariadb

I'm newbie on website, and I'm using django with the mariadb.

I already have mariadb database to use, and this is my new (basic) website so there are no functions yet.

To migrate the origin DB to django, my command was
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
but the error
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]
occurs.

What I can't understand is that I don't have any other code without the basic structure code.
What I only did was to run the command
django-admin startproject mysite
python manage.py startapp board

How can I fix this error?

Search for an hour, but couldn't find the answer.

Comment: Show us the model that led to that error.

Comment: That's what I really cannot understand, since my models.py is not written yet. This is my models.py code.                     

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

Comment: I solve this problem by downgrading the mariadb version from 11 to 10. Thank you for your concern.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.